# c++ problem with enum and struct

Tags: c++, enums, struct

why doesn't this compile:

```
enum E { a, b}

typedef struct { int i; E e; } S;

int main(){return 0;}
```

I get different errors on different system.

Comment: something about having 2 types before the `e`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a semicolon after the `enum`.

```
enum E { a, b};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't the error in the real thing, but I did find it. (Darn I hate C)

Answer (score 0):

The enum needs an `;` after its `}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no semicolon after the enum.

Answer (score 0):

no semi colon at the end of enum